# What happend if guava cache is full and no evictable element?

Tags: caching, guava, google-guava-cache

I am using google guava cache with reference-based eviction.
I wonder what happened if the cache is full and no element of it is marked as evictable? Is there an out of memory exception thrown?

Comment: The JVM will eventually throw an `OutOfMemoryError` if the application cannot allocate new objects. A reference-based cache has no explicit capacity limit, so full means there is no free memory available.

Comment: There's no such thing in Guava's cache as "evictable" or "not evictable."  The cache has automatic eviction, or it doesn't.  If it doesn't, it will eventually OutOfMemoryError just like every other data structure in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Reference-based eviction is essentially no different than Java's standard GC behavior - the GC just ignores the reference's presence in the cache. If an object falls out of scope (everywhere but the cache) it will be evicted from the cache during GC. If all elements of the cache are in scope somewhere else and therefore cannot be GCed you will run into memory problems exactly like you would if you weren't using a cache. You cannot have more data in memory than the JVM is configured to permit. Using a reference-evicting cache doesn't change this.